# Can I extract a selection from a page into a new file in a single step?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I'd like to easily create clippings that aren't simply bitmap screenshots (i.e., I don't want to use the snapshot tool.) The only way I know how to do this is to open the "pages" view, extract the current page to a new file, and then crop the page down to the desired clipping in the new file.

Ideally instead I would simply select what I want to extract from the current view and the selection would extract directly into a new pdf. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Place the PDF in InDesign and crop the pages to your liking perhaps? I don't know what you mean by "extract it directly". The data has to go somewhere so if not into a PDF then where?

Comment: @Wolff See my answer below. What I mean by "extracting it directly" is that I would like to select part of a page and extract it to a new pdf. I would call this something like "make a clipping."

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, it appears that this task is beyond Adobe's technological reach. However, you can make the process a little less onerous by enabling "single key accelerators to access tools" in the general settings. Then use <kbd>C</kbd> to get the crop tool.

For the extract pages dialog, there is no keyboard shortcut. One way to ease this is to customize the main toolbar with the extract pages tool. You can get a keyboard shortcut by using a script such as [the one found on this page.](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/request-for-keyboard-shortcut-to-extract-pages/td-p/9984061)